# EF Core - create relation between two models without a foreign key constaint

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a microservice system where I replicate `Users` and `Tokens` across multiple services.

Sometimes, `Token` is received before `User` that it belongs to and I get an error:

```
MessageText: insert or update on table "Tokens" violates foreign key constraint "FK_Tokens_User_UserId"
Detail: Key (UserId)=(12) is not present in table "User".
```

Is there a way in EFCore to have relations with navigational properties, but without the constraint - so I can add `Token` with a not-yet-existing `Id` as foreign key, that'll eventually be consistent?

Here's the models:

Token:

```
public class Token
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long? UserId { get; set; }
    
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

User:

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Token> Tokens { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the portion of migration.designer.cs generating foreign key:

```
modelBuilder.Entity("Vehicloo.NoticeboardService.Database.Models.Token", b =>
{
    b.HasOne("Vehicloo.NoticeboardService.Database.Models.User", "User")
        .WithMany("Tokens")
        .HasForeignKey("UserId");

    b.Navigation("User");
});
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the EF entities you have defined. Does your code work when you remove the foreign key from the database?

Comment: @Progman My code works fine. As I stated in my post: I'm adding Token with foreign key `UserId` equal to `12` - `User` with that `Id` doesn't exist at that time. What I'm trying to do is remove foreign key constraint.

Comment: If you want to add a value `12` in the `UserId` column, but it is set as a foreign key to `User` and there is no such a row, then you must remove the foreign key or add the `User` row with that id. The error message about foreign key violation is coming from PostgreSQL, not from Entity Framework.

Comment: @Progman Yes, but the foreign key is created by EFCore. Once again - as I stated in my post: 'Is there a way in EFCore to have relations with navigational properties, but without the constraint'.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code which created the foreign key via EFCore.

Comment: @Progman it's typical model with navigational properties and properties for foreign keys, but alright.

Comment: Defining the model itself does not create the tables (or foreign keys) in the database, other code like `OnModelCreating()` or migration does. Please include the code which generated the tables and foreign keys in the database.

Comment: @Progman It does thought. My `OnModelCreating()` is empty, I just generate migration and run `update-database`.

Comment: I think Progman is asking for the relevant entity section of the *.Designer.cs file.  That shows how the ModelBuilder actually setup this table.

Comment: @JCode As you used migrations, you might want to use [`MigrationBuilder.DropForeignKey()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.dropforeignkey?view=efcore-5.0) to remove the foreign keys you don't want.

Comment: @BryanLewis Added. @Progman I'm trying to avoid having to modify migrations each time I generate them - I was thinking there was an EFCore model-definition option like adding attribute `[StringLength(255)]` makes migration generate column with specified maximum length.

Comment: @JCode You might want to check https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21512, looks like they don't like such a direction option. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli you might consider using only SQL scripts for migrations, as it is the recommended way.

Comment: @Progman I wish I could put it in `OnModelCreating()` or something rather than the migration hmm.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove line:

```
public virtual ICollection<Token> Tokens { get; set; }
```

from `User` and this line:

```
public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

from `Token`. This tells `EF` not create any foreign key for the User-Token. Consequently, you will have the `UserId` column in the `Token` table without any constraint.

For queries, you can join two table manually.

Comment: I'm trying to keep the navigational properties working - they are vital for my API, as I use HotChocolate lib and it utilizes them to fetch related models (it can't perform joins on it's own).

Comment: @JCode, I am afraid you have no other choice other than have navigation WITH forced constraint or not having the navigation at all.

Comment: or removing constraint after migration... which is also tedious.